# Encrypting Passwords in Ironspeed 6.1.1

Tags: encryption, ironspeed

I'm currently working on an app that is being created using Ironspeed Designer.  It's going to be an internet website with sensitive data, so we (my group) would like to encrypt passwords.

According to [this help article](http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/6.1.1/WebHelp/Iron_Speed_Designer_Help.htm#Part_III/Part_III_Configuring_Component_Properties.htm) at Ironspeed's site, the customization to do this sounds trivial.  Except I can't find the file I'm supposed to modify: \\App_Code\Users\AddUsers.Controls.c does not exist.  I have run the security wizard for my app.  I was thinking this article was referencing a larger series of customizations but I haven't found anything to indicate whether that is the case.

I'm hoping someone here has gone down this road before and can help get me back on track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped to look at the application in Visual Studio (and there was the file).  I don't really have a lot of Ironspeed experience (I didn't before starting this project, anyway), so some of this stuff is like ramming my head against a brick wall until "hey, a window!".

I'd prefer to have no ironspeed experience in the grand scheme of things, but that is neither here nor there.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddUsers.Controls.cs` file will be in the `App_Code\Users` folder.  Note that Iron Speed uses the name of the table in its folder and page naming.  For example, if you have a customers table in your database, you will see an `AddCustomers.Controls.cs` in the `App_Code\Customers` folder.  So the example is based on you having a `Users` table.  If your table is called something else, the corresponding name will change based on the name of the table.